# REDCap Question- Wanting to create a calculated field that sums individual answers in a matrix

Tags: redcap

We have a matrix of questions that use a scoring system (e.g. S/Agree = 1 Agree = 2, Mutual = 3, Disagree = 4, S/Disagree = 5) that we have to sum at the end of each matrix.
When I use the usual SUM([Field name],[field name]) it does not work as I would usually do if the questions where all inputted individually.
Is there a specific calculation that I need to take into consideration when calculating matrix's?
Thanks

SUM([Field name],[field name])

Comment: I don't get the same result. Note however, when I form the equation using `sum([this_one], [that_one], [the_other_one])` and select a record in "Test calculation with a record", the UI tells me 'Result: [No value]'. Yet when I go to the record page itself, the calculated field is showing the desired result. I also get the result in the data export. Could you potentially share a couple of screen shots of what you matrix set up is and what you're seeing for a result?

Comment: Note that functions are case-sensitive, so try lowercase `sum([field_1],[field_2]...)`.